# Undefined local variable or method for class working with Paperclip-Dropbox gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, paperclip

Undefined local variable or method `listing' for #<#:0x00000104e1fca8>

Is the error I am receiving.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="thumbnail">
    <%= image_tag listing.image.url %>
 </div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3><%= @listing.name %></h3>
    <p><%= number_to_currency(@listing.price, :unit => "£") %></p>
    <p><%= @listing.vendor %></p>
    <p><%= @listing.description %></p>
 </div>
</div>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_listing_path(@listing), class: "btn btn-link" %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', listings_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error says

> Undefined local variable or method `listing' for #<#:0x00000104e1fca8>

*So in your code somewhere you are using listing which is not defined by you*.

Use:

```
<%= image_tag @listing.image.url %>
```

**Notice i'm using @listing and not listing**

**Update**

In index.html.erb you would have a something like

```
@listings.each do |listing| 
  // this makes listing available so you can use
  <%= listing.image.url %>
end
```

Comment: Thanks Mandeep. That has fixed my problem which is great. Curious to know though why in my index.html.erb I have <%= image_tag listing.image.url %> which works and I haven't defined it as a variable?

Answer (score 1):

looks like your problem deals with scope. In Ruby here are the different types of variables.

```
Local Variables
Instance Variables
Class Variables
Global Variables
```

In your image_tag, you specified a local variable, listing. The scope of that variable should be changed to an instance variable, which is preceded by an @ symbol

```
<%= image_tag listing.image.url %>
```

should become

```
<%= image_tag @listing.image.url %>
```

This should fix your issue, and you will no longer receive the local variable error.